# How to add add a Qt debug helper for obfuscated memory?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I would like to add a [Qt Creator Debugging Helper](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html) for a class like the following (assume there is some in place construction going on, and lots of methods like rawData() that could be called).  Thus far I have failed to make any helper that does better than simply disabling inspection of the type entirely.

Is there a magic incantation to simply proxy inspection to std::string?

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class C
{
private:
    using type = typename std::aligned_storage<
                 sizeof(std::string), 
                 alignof(std::string)>::type;
    type storage;
public:
    const char* rawData()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<std::string&>(storage).data();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @JarMan totally reasonable request... but everything I tried had negative impact (broke the inspection of that type entirely) so I didn't feel my experiments would add much value.  That being said, I tried and failed to use various combinations of putArrayData, putType, putBetterType, createType, and from Dumper.Value: dereference, address, cast, data.  It's pretty clear that I fundamentally don't understand how to use/debug these helpers.